# Cannot resolve Snackbar.make() in android

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I am trying to display a snackbar in my MainActivity code. The method which is called to display the snackbar is as follows.

```
private void showSnackBar(int content_string, int action_string,
                          View.OnClickListener listener) {

    Snackbar.make(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout,
            getString(explanation_string),
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
    .setAction(getString(action_string), listener)
    .show();
}
```

And I call this method using the following call

```
showSnackBar(R.string.content_string,
                R.string.action_string,
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       //Some operation
                    }
                });
```

But, inside the showSnackbar method I get an error saying the Snackbar.show(int,java.lang.String,int) cannot be resolved. It would be helpful if someone could point out what am I missing here, which is the error.
These are the dependencies which I have added in the build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0"
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
```

Comment: Make sure added `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yes its there in the build.gradle file. Without that I would noi have been include CoordinatorLayout .

Comment: The `SnackBar` documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) clearly shows that `make` requires a View, a charsequence or an int (as resource) and an int. You are throwing in an id of some layout. You will need to inflate that layout yourself

Answer (score 1):

now in 02/06/2018 the configuration 'compile' was changed for 'implementation'
like this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration?utm_source=android-studio#new_configurations

Answer (score 0):

Snackbar takes a `View` as the first parameter rather than the id of the view. Here's the [docs for the method.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#make(android.view.View,%20int,%20int))

```
make(View view, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

So instead of passing the id, pass inflated view.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Completely missed a small but important detail. I was just passing the id of the view, instead of the whole inflated view.

Comment: Yeah, just pay attention to that. A very useful shortcut that can save your life is `CMD+P` (`CTRL+P` on Win) when you're inside of the brackets of a method, to check what parameters it takes. Consider accepting the answer if it helped you, cheers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Will make sure to use this handy shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Snackbars](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html)** provide lightweight feedback about an operation. They show a
>   brief message at the bottom of the screen on mobile and lower left on
>   larger devices.

***Compile with***

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

**FYI**

**First Parameter** should be **`CoordinatorLayout's Object`** instead of **`R.id`** .

```
Snackbar.make(myCoordinatorLayoutOBJ,getString(explanation_string),Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction(getString(action_string), listener).show();
```

Comment: @AshwinKumar move ahead .